# Apply Left Join in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, left-join

```
SELECT *
FROM user
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(uid)
        FROM union_user
        ORDER BY uid DESC
    ) union_user
    ON union_user.uid = user.id
```

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: This is only a SQL query. Are you having issues with the SQL, laravel usage, or some PHP cross issue? Please always put a description with your questions. Code dumps provide very little information about the issue.

Comment: Look at the docs before asking questions like this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you

```
$user = DB::table('users')
                ->leftJoin('union_user', 'users.id', '=', 'union_user.user_id')
                ->orderBy(union_user.user_id)
                ->max('union_user.user_id');
```